# Как в вебформе битрикса добавить поле checkbox?

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день, уважаемые любители битрикса!
Мне необходимо в уже готовую форму добавить checkbox с текстом "даю согласие на отправку персональных данных".
Пытался сформировать в вебформе вопрос, но непонятно как это правильно сделать.
Также непонятно как сделать валидацию данного поля.
Нужно чтобы если чекбокс не checked, форма не отправлялась.
Буду очень благодарен за любую информацию по этому вопросу, так как нигде в интернете её нет.
Также прошу не давать ссылки на документацию битрикса, если там нет решения, конкретно моего вопроса.
Спасибо!

Comment: Вообще, в битриксе появился функционал, который создан специально для того, что Вы пытаетесь сделать - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/silaev/comply-with-the-law-fz152-on-personal-data.php Здесь инструкция, как добавить в любые типы форм галку с пользовательским соглашением. Соответственно, если все сделать верно, форма без данной галки не отправится

Comment: Попробуйте поставить галочку обязательно http://joxi.ru/52ab137UGy4ZVA

Answer (score 0):

В веб-формах создаешь новый вопрос, ставишь "Поле ответа обязательно для заполнения", "Тип поля для ответа" выбираешь checkbox, в вариантах ответа ставишь один вариант (можно просто пробелы поставить) и все, должно заработать и да, сам вопрос не забудь указать

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает. Форма отправляется независимо от того чекнут чекбокс или нет.

Comment: а можешь скрин показать где настройка ответов?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Vrw9a0ZTKwBw62

Comment: шаблон полностью стандартный?

Comment: нет, шаблон кастомный

Comment: для чистоты эксперимента, попробуйте на дэфолтном выполнить сперва